# Getting Started with Sharepoint 2010 Development with no prior Sharepoint knowledge

Tags: development

My boss wants me to learn Sharepoint 2010 development (and he wants me to learn it now!).  I have never done anything with Sharepoint.  Where should I start?

About Me:  I am an Asp.net developer, and I know my way around .Net and the web ... I just never had any interest in Sharepoint (until now).

Comment: This type of open ended question should always be created as a 'community wiki'

Comment: @Charles - Thanks.  I never know what classifies, so I always just wait for someone to suggest it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy Sahil Malik's Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Building Solutions for sharepoint 2010 book from appress.

The tutorials on Channel 9/Microsoft are excellent for SP2010 however, setting up a development environment or using a VM will be extremely useful for you to get a good learning experience.  Sahil Malik's book has a information on setting up a dev environment.  Key for me is have AD, SP2010 Enterprise & SQL developer edition on each development machine.
**More Info on Setup:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx
http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/sp2010/Building+a+SharePoint+2010+Development+machine

If you have a technet subscription you have all the software licences to build a complete developer machine with the exception of Visual Studio 2010.  I would use HyperV running Windows 2008 R2.  As your setup will be the easiest. Tip: When installing SP2010 do't go for the staldalone option.

All the additional dev tools I use are listed here:
http://sp2010uk.blogspot.com/2010/06/developer-sharepoint-machine-prep.html

Comment: @Paul - got the book, started reading it last night.  It already answer my question about development environment.  (Side note: the editing in the book sucks!)

Answer (score 2):

I've just published an article on our company blog on this subject. I started working with SharePoint in 2010, having had only used it as an end user previously:

[10 things developers should know about SharePoint](http://bit.ly/K7WoSG)

Here are the main points from the article (I'm not going to post all 1500+ words of it here...):

**Pitfalls**

- Know your Editions
- Don’t even look at the database
- Get to know the front-end
- Dispose of your disposables

**Building your Knowledge**

- Learn the terminology
- Get a good book
- Love the MSDN documentation
- Find a SharePoint community that suits you

**General advice**

- Learn to live with CAML
- Remember that SharePoint is enormous

Answer (score 1):

Start here with Microsoft's online developer getting started training:
http://MSSharePointDeveloper.com

There is also training and certification for SharePoint 2010 available from Microsoft Learning.
http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/training/sharepoint.aspx

Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

For installation of tools, use the [SharePoint 2010 Easy Setup Script](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=54dc2eef-e9ea-4c7b-9470-ec5cb58414de) provided by Microsoft. It consists of PowerShell scripts that help you install:

- SharePoint Server 2010 + pre-requisites (Standalone)
- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition
- Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio
- Expression Studio 4 Ultimate
- Open XML SDK
- Visual Studio SDK
- Visual Studio SharePoint Power Tools
- Office 2010 Professional Plus
- SharePoint Designer 2010
- Visio 2010

Answer (score 0):

I tend to find the channel 9 msdn videos are good for getting a leg up on dev, here's a couple for starters:

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/funkyonex/Overview-of-SharePoint-Development-in-Visual-Studio-2010/

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513147.aspx

Have a look about on those sites for more.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good resources:

The microsoft SharePoint developer center 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/default.aspx

SP Dev Wiki
http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/

Answer (score 0):

i have a question? Is there any reason not to use the "2010 Information Worker Demonstration and Evaluation Virtual Machine (RTM)" for SharePoint development? In my opinion this image has all needed stuff installed with some demo data.

Links:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=751fa0d1-356c-4002-9c60-d539896c66ce&displaylang=en

(sorry for my english, i'm new here and in SharePoint development)

Comment: I think the restrictions come down to licensing (this will need verification) - it's an evaluation system therefore it's licensed for testing. Development may require licenses targeted for developers (as in, MSDN subscriptions or similar). However, if you are learning development, and not using it to make products to use commercially, then I think the restriction is more valid.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. See [How do I ask questions here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for further help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add:

Patience. Loads of it.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Learn PowerShell - [PowerShell for Developers - Part 1.](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/SharePoint-PowerShell-for-Developers-Part-1.aspx)

James Love has an excellent post about learning SharePoint development here - [SharePoint Development - What to Learn?](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/SharePoint-Development-What-to-Learn.aspx)

Albeit CAML has its place, learning LINQ is increasingly important - [Getting started with LINQ to SharePoint in SharePoint 2010.](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-getting-started-with-linq-to-sharepoint-in-sharepoint-2010)